# How to access different values of a key in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a dictionary with key with multiple values. How can I access those values from single key?

```
d = {'a':(1,2,3),('b','c'):5}
```

I want to access the values 1,2 or 3 using the key 'a'.

Comment: `d['a'][0]`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d['a']` is a tuple, and like any tuple you can access it's elements as such: `d['a'][0]` which holds the value 1